# Mouse Event: the order of operations

Tags: java, events, javafx

I have a problem with mouse event. Some code seems to be done before other. I write a GO game with Monte Carlo simulation.

```
holder.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(mouseX > 0 && mouseY > 0 && player1){
                    boolean[][] availableFields =  GameBoard.checkAvailableFields(GameBoard.stoneColor.WHITE);

                    if (availableFields[arrayX][arrayY] == true) {
                        System.out.println("White rock on " + arrayX + ", " + arrayY);
                        putRock(arrayX, arrayY, GameBoard.stoneColor.WHITE);
                        gameBoard.setField(arrayX, arrayY, GameBoard.stoneColor.WHITE);
                        player1 = false;
                        System.out.println("Rock put");
                    } else{
                        System.out.println("no put");
                    }

                    gameBoard.printFields();

                    MonteCarlo montecarlo = new MonteCarlo(gameBoard);
                    int field = montecarlo.nextMove();
                    int x = field % 5;
                    int y = field / 5;
                    arrayToMouseXY(x, y);
                    arrayX = x;
                    arrayY = y;
                    System.out.println("Black rock on " + field + ": " + arrayX + ", " + arrayY);
                    putRock(arrayX, arrayY, GameBoard.stoneColor.BLACK);
                    gameBoard.setField(arrayX, arrayY, GameBoard.stoneColor.BLACK);
                    player1 = true;

                    gameBoard.printFields();
                }
            }
        });
```

The function `putRock(int x, int y, GameBoard.stoneColor color)` draws an image on the screen. The problem is that first rock isn't painted until the whole Monte Carlo simulation is computed. How could I prevent this?

Comment: And is this because drawing is executed after exiting event handler? So that is why I need another thread? Am I right?

Comment: @James_D is right; I misread.

Comment: @KamilaO Yes, pretty much. Event handlers are executed on the FX Application Thread, which is the same thread that is (effectively) used to perform the actual rendering of the scene. So if you have code in the event handler that blocks execution, no changes can be physically rendered to the scene graph until that execution is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like to run the simulation on a background thread, and update the GUI with the step that the result of your simulation as soon as the background thread finished.

**Example:**

```
// Task for your simulation
Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>(){

    @Override
    protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        MonteCarlo montecarlo = new MonteCarlo(gameBoard);
        return montecarlo.nextMove();
    }

};

// If you want to disable the GUI while your simulation runs (root is the root Node of your Scene graph)
// root.setDisable(true); 

// When the task finished, update the GUI with the step
task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
        int field = task.getValue();
        int x = field % 5;
        int y = field / 5;
        arrayToMouseXY(x, y);
        arrayX = x;
        arrayY = y;
        System.out.println("Black rock on " + field + ": " + arrayX + ", " + arrayY);
        putRock(arrayX, arrayY, GameBoard.stoneColor.BLACK);
        gameBoard.setField(arrayX, arrayY, GameBoard.stoneColor.BLACK);
        player1 = true;

        gameBoard.printFields();
        // "release" the GUI
        // root.setDisable(false); 
    }
});

// Start the thread
Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```